# A selector to match the first item that doesn't have some class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Assuming I have a list like this one:

```
<ul>
    <li class="hidden">Horse</li>
    <li>Bear</li>
    <li>Cat</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to get the first li item that doesn't has the class `.hidden`, [I tried this](http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/ANvDP/2/) and many others but it didn't work:

```
li:not(.hidden):nth-child(1) {
    /* ... */
}
```

#### [Fiddle with test](http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/ANvDP/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/580587) explains this topic in great detail. Using the solution of "apply to all of them, then remove everything except the first" works on your Fiddle:

```
li:not(.hidden){
    color: #0F0;
}

li:not(.hidden) ~ li:not(.hidden){
    color: inherit;
}
```